# PHPの、 'A and B;' の文法について

Tags: php

PHP初心者です。
FuelPHPのソースコードリーディングをしていたところ、Requestクラスのforgeメソッドに↓のような記述がありました。

```
is_bool($options) and $options = array('route' => $options);
is_string($options) and $options = array('driver' => $options);
```

この記述はどういう意味になるのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

↓リクエストクラスの全文はこちらです。

```
public static function forge($uri = null, $options = true, $method = null)
{
    is_bool($options) and $options = array('route' => $options);
    is_string($options) and $options = array('driver' => $options);

    if ( ! empty($options['driver']))
    {
        $class = \Inflector::words_to_upper('Request_'.$options['driver']);
        return $class::forge($uri, $options, $method);
    }

    $request = new static($uri, isset($options['route']) ? $options['route'] : true, $method);
    if (static::$active)
    {
        $request->parent = static::$active;
        static::$active->children[] = $request;
    }

    // fire any request created events
    \Event::instance()->has_events('request_created') and \Event::instance()->trigger('request_created', '', 'none');

    return $request;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

短絡評価ってヤツですね。
言語によっては短絡評価を行わないものもあるので注意ですが...

『A and B』という論理演算があった場合、AがfalseだとBを評価する前に『A and B』の結果がfalseと確定します。なので、Bの処理や評価を行う必要が無いのでしません。これを短絡評価と言います。
逆にAがtrueだとBの結果を得ないと『A and B』の結果が確定しませんよね？なので、Aがtrueの時のみBの処理を行います。

同じように『A or B』とあった場合、AがtrueだとBを評価する前に『A or B』の結果がtrueと確定します。逆にAがfalseだとBの結果を得ないと『A or B』の結果が確定しません。なので、Aがfalseの時のみBの処理を行います。

上記のような、仕様を利用してif文を短く書くことができます。JavaScriptやSh Scriptでもよく使われる書き方です。

http://php.net/manual/ja/language.operators.logical.php

分かりやすく書きかえるとこんな感じですかね。

```
if(is_bool($options))
{
  $options = array('route' => $options);
}

if(is_string($options))
{
  $options = array('driver' => $options);
}
```